# Scaling up kafka consumer applications

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Lets say I have one consumer group which subscribed to **4 topics** and partitions for each topics are:-

**EDITED:**

1. First topic => 5 partitions
2. Second topic => 3 partitions
3. Third topic => 2 partitions
4. Fourth topic => 1 partitions

Total number of **partitions = 11**. So total how many applications I can run.

`5(max number of partitions in input topics) or 11?`

Comment: do you mean how many consumers can read from each topic in parallel?

Comment: yes how many applications I can run

Comment: How many threads/consumers do you have per application? Assuming 1, the answer is the sum of the partitions, not topics

Comment: Yes there is one thread. Is it true in kafka streams also?

Answer (score 0):

In kafka, scaling consumers depends on partition number.

Lets assume you have one topic with 3 partitions. And you have 2 different consumer app (different consumer groups) which does different works.

You can scale your consumer number up to 3 for per consumer group.

- Single consumer (consumer group A) can consume messages from 3
  partitions.
- Two consumer (same consumer group) can not consume single
  partition.

Take look at image : https://hadoopabcd.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/consumer-group.png

Read more about consumer groups blog series : https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-kafka-consumer-groups-and-consumer-l

Answer (score 0):

In ideal situation the number of consumer in the consumer group should be equal to the number of partition. If that is not the case then you can have more then one consumer group kafka provides the feature that 2 consumer from the different consumer group can read from the same partition. That’s totally depends on your resources how many resources do you have for running the consumers.

Suppose you have an application that needs to read messages from a Kafka topic, run some validations against them, and write the results to another data store. In this case your application will create a consumer object, subscribe to the appropriate topic, and start receiving messages, validating them and writing the results. This may work well for a while, but what if the rate at which producers write messages to the topic exceeds the rate at which your application can validate them? If you are limited to a single consumer reading and processing the data, your application may fall farther and farther behind, unable to keep up with the rate of incoming messages. Obviously there is a need to scale consumption from topics. Just like multiple producers can write to the same topic, we need to allow multiple consumers to read from the same topic, splitting the data between them.

Kafka consumers are typically part of a consumer group. When multiple consumers are subscribed to a topic and belong to the same consumer group, each consumer in the group will receive messages from a different subset of the partitions in the topic.

> Please refer to this https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/kafka-the-definitive/9781491936153/ch04.html

Comment: Please read this article https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/